# Google Glass Sample Card App Crashed

Tags: google-glass

Hi guys I have developed sample card application for google glass which was working fine before updating glass firmware , but now when I open it shows exception

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.android.glass.app.Card.setInfo

I have already reinstalled it many times but it is not working!
what to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you've updated your copy of the `Glass Development Kit Sneak Peek` in the Android SDK Manager whenever you get a new XE release on Glass. The `Card` class's `setInfo` method was renamed to `setFootnote` in XE12.

Comment: ahhh I am on it ! hope for the best